shopify billing api using store plan
So I want to create a monthly and yearly billing plan for my app using the store plan that the client has chosen. For eg, if the client has chosen the advanced shopify plan for the store then I want to show a monthly and yearly advanced shopify plan for my app.
Can anyone guide me how can I achieve that.
Already I have tried fetching data form the graphql and rest admin apis about the store plan and it is showing me partner_test.
I was planning on fetching the store plan and match it with my billing plans and render them on the app but that would require the codes for all other plans.
Is there a better way of solving this problem? I have attached the image about the details that I am receiving from the admin api (above) and rest api (below).

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
